# How to convert Flux of DataBuffer to Mono of byte array in Project Reactor?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

There is a `Flux<DataBuffer>`. What is the natural way of converting it to `Mono<byte[]>`?

```
Mono<byte[]> mergeDataBuffers(Flux<DataBuffer> flux){
  // ?
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils` to join the DataBuffers from the `Flux<DataBuffer>` into a single `DataBuffer`, and then read that buffer into a byte array.

```java
    Mono<byte[]> mergeDataBuffers(Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux) {
        return DataBufferUtils.join(dataBufferFlux)
                .map(dataBuffer -> {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                    dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                    DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                    return bytes;
                });
    }
```

Be sure to take memory usage into consideration when doing so, since this approach will load all of the data into memory twice (once in the DataBuffers, and then again when copied into the `byte[]`).

Comment: Thank you, Phil. What do you think about  `DataBufferUtils.join(dataBufferFlux).map(dbuf -> dbuf.asByteBuffer().array())`? And could you elaborate on `DataBufferUtils.release`: I tried with and without it and found no visible influence on memory (used VisualVM).

Comment: `dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().array()` is not guaranteed to work for all implementations, since not all implementations have a backing array.
`DataBufferUtils.release` needs to be called when your code is finished using the `DataBuffer`, and it is no longer referenced.  It is required to properly handle reference counting for `PooledDataBuffer`s. See also https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#databuffers-using

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        PipedOutputStream osPipe = new PipedOutputStream();
        PipedInputStream isPipe = new PipedInputStream(osPipe);
        DataBufferUtils.write(data, osPipe)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                    try {
                        osPipe.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer());
        return IOUtils.toString(isPipe, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

**subscribe is async, this may not get data**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: beware of memory leak here because when you `subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())` the thread completing the write operation may not be the same thread you subscribe on hence the `doOnComplete()` may not be executed and thus leading to the `PipedOutputStream` not closed